# Rails: How to use default layout if It layout file is missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout

How to use default layout if It layout file is missing?

I have folder `layouts/themes/` that contains themes, but I want to load default theme if file is not exist.

I tried to set `rescue_from  ActionView:MissingTemplate, with => ...` but I can't set layout in such way.

So the best solution that I found is:
layout :layout_by_resource

```
def layout_by_resource
  layout_name = "themes/" + current_theme
  File.exists?(Rails.root + "app/views/layouts/" + (layout_name + ".html.erb")) ? layout_name : "application"
end
```

Is there better solution for such purpose?

Comment: better: `Rails.root.join 'app', 'views, 'layouts', layout_name + '.html.erb'`

Comment: What do you mean by better? If you have it in your ApplicationController it will work for all the controllers in your app. This is a good solution.

Comment: I meant something without File.exists? :) May be somethiong with `rescue_from`

Answer (score 1):

In Rails layouts are stored in `app/views/layouts` and default layout name is `application.html.erb` and it is used if there is no layout that's name correspond with controller name. For example, photos controller would have `photos.html.erb` layout.

For more details look [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render) (section 2.2.13)

Comment: Yes, but if the layout is explicitly set to a non-existing template, ActionView::MisingTemplate will be raised instead

Comment: So I consider it as a bug in application. Why don't you just change it in the code? Why assign custom template names and don't use default ones?

Comment: Have you read this page I included in my answer? There you have some examples how to assign it at runtime

Comment: I can't assign layout after cath exception

Comment: I guess that when you catch exception, it is too late. In my opinion, if you don't have template and execption is generated, then it is a signal that your application code is wrong. Why do you want to handle it in runtime?